# How to add a VMware fusion shared folder mount to /etc/fstab?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, vmware-fusion, fstab

I'm mounting a VMware Fusion shared folder (vmhgfs) called `foo` to `/var/www` using the following command:

```
mount -t vmhgfs .host:/foo /var/www/
```

This works fine and creates the following `/etc/mtab` entry:

```
.host:/foo /var/www vmhgfs rw,ttl=1 0 0
```

However, when copying that entry to `/etc/fstab`, system startup fails to mount the share. If I drop into a shell at the moment of the error, the main `/mnt/hgfs` mount which VMware creates automatically is also not mounted, so I'm guessing it's trying to mount before the VMware tools are loaded or something like that?!

OS is Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Comment: Maybe you want to add "noauto" to fstab, and mount within kde/unity logon script?

Comment: It's an Ubuntu server. When would it be mounted with noauto if there is no unity?

Comment: As soon as you run `mount /my/mountpoint`. It's still shorter than typing everything every time, I think.